# Map nested vector of array maps

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I've been trying to map the nested values of a map within a vector into a vector of vectors without success.

The data I have is like this:

```
[{:country {:name "chile", :id 1},
  :subcountries [{:name "talca", :id 2}
                 {:name "concepcion", :id 3}
                 {:name "puerto montt", :id 4}]}
 {:country {:name "united states", :id 5},
  :subcountries [{:name "boston", :id 6}
                 {:name "texas", :id 7}]}]
```

While the code I've been playing with vaguely returns an approximation of what I'm trying to get as a result:

```
(map
 (fn [x]
   (let [{{id :id name :name} :country
          subcountries :subcountries} x]
     [id
      name
      (map (fn [y] (let [{yid :id yname :yname} y] [yid yname])))]))
 data)
```

The result I'm receiving with that is something pretty odd, since the vector I'd want to have is just a function:

```
([1 "chile" #function[clojure.core/map/fn--5862]]
 [5 "united states" #function[clojure.core/map/fn--5862]])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Expected output should be something like:

```
[[["chile" 1] ["talca" 2] ["concepcion" 3] ["puerto montt" 4]]
 [["united states" 5] ["boston" 6] ["texas" 7]]]
```

Comment: What is your desired output for shown sample of data?

Comment: Sorry, didn't add that, I do it ...

Comment: Really what I'm trying to do is to map `data` into a vector of `option` tags (clojure script) using the `name` as the `inner text` and the `id` as the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the function in your vector output is that your inner `map` wasn't applying the function to any data structure, so it was returning a transducer.

Here I've updated the inner `map` to map the function to the subcountries, which I assume was your intent. (There was also a tiny typo, you had `yname :yname` instead of `yname :name`)

```
(defn f [data]
  (mapv
   (fn [x]
     (let [{{id :id name :name} :country
            subcountries :subcountries} x]
       [id
        name
        (mapv (fn [y] (let [{yid :id yname :name} y] [yid yname])) subcountries)]))
   data))
```

Not sure if this is exactly your desired output, since you said "something like...". If not, let us know if you need more help getting it the rest of the way there.

```
> (f data)
[[1 "chile" [[2 "talca"] [3 "concepcion"] [4 "puerto montt"]]]
 [5 "united states" [[6 "boston"] [7 "texas"]]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be a more "Clojurey" way to do it:

```
(defn countries->vecs [data]
  (let [->pair (juxt :name :id)
        map->pairs (fn [{:keys [country subcountries]}]
                     (apply vector (->pair country) 
                                   (map ->pair subcountries)))]
    (mapv map->pairs data)))
```

Comment: `->pair` pulls out the `:name` and `:id` values from a map `((juxt :name :id) {:name "chile", :id 1}) => ["chile" 1]` and `map->pairs` makes the vector of pair vectors for a country/subcountry map. `(map->pairs {:country {:name "united states", :id 5}, :subcountries [{:name "boston", :id 6}  {:name "texas", :id 7}]}) => [["united states" 5] ["boston" 6] ["texas" 7]]`